# Calling a function after a click on a button in Wordpress (dev-plugin)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

This is my code and I wanna do what is commented near line 73 (//HOW CAN I CALL FUNCTION post_type_search_callback HERE???). The results need to be in the same page, below the "form". I was trying some tutorials about ajax in the web but without succeeded. Pls help! Thanks!

```html
<?php

class OwnersTriplify {

 const plugin_name = 'Owners-triplify';

 public static function head() {

 }

 public static function initialize() {

  add_action('admin_menu', 'owners_triplify_admin_actions');

  function owners_triplify_admin_actions() {
  
  add_menu_page('Owners Triplify', 'Owners Triplify', 'manage_options', 'owners-triplify/includes/OwnersTriplify.php', 'owners_triplify', plugins_url('owners-triplify/images/icon.png'));
  
  }

  function register_my_setting() {
  
  register_setting( 'hd-group', 'hd_options'); 
 
  }

  add_action( 'admin_init', 'register_my_setting' );

  add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'post_type_search_enqueue' );

  function post_type_search_enqueue($hook) {
       
   if( 'index.php' != $hook ) {
 
    // Only applies to dashboard panel
    return;
       }
        
   wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script', plugins_url( '/js/post_type_search_query.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery') );
   
   // in JavaScript, object properties are accessed as ajax_object.ajax_url, ajax_object.we_value
   
   wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'ajax_object',
            
   array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ), 'we_value' => 1234 ) );
  }

  function owners_triplify() {

   ?>

   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

   <div id="div1">

    <h3>Digite o post-type que deseja triplificar: </h3>
    <br/>
     <form method="post" name="form1" action="">
      <input name="postType" value="" id="postType">
      <input type="hidden" name="action" value="update">
      <input type="hidden" name="option_page" value="hd_options">
      <button id="button1" name="termoPesquisado" type="submit" class="button-primary">Pesquisar</button>
     </form> 
    <br/>

   </div>

   <script>

    $("#button1").click(function () {

     //HOW CAN I CALL FUNCTION post_type_search_callback HERE???

    });

    /*$("#button1").click(function () {

     if ( $("#div2").is( ":hidden" ) ) {
      
      $("#div2").slideDown();
      
      $("#div1").hide();

      } 

      else {
      
      }

    });*/

   </script>

  <?php

  }

  function pegaValores($data) {

   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;

  }

  $termo = pegaValores($_POST["postType"]);

  ?>

  <?php

  add_action('wp_ajax_post_type_search', 'post_type_search_callback');

  function post_type_search_callback() {

   ?>

   <div id="div2">

   <h3>Digite as equivalências: </h3>

   <?php

   global $wpdb;
   $resultado = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT distinct meta_key FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE post_id in(SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = '".$termo."')");
   $correspondencias;
   $tamanhoResultado = count($resultado);
   
   for($i = 1; $i <= $tamanhoResultado; $i++) {

    $correspondencias[$i] = "correspondencia";

   }
   
   $contador = 1;

   //$resultado_array = array();

   foreach($resultado as $resultadoX) {

    echo "<p>". 
    $resultado_array[] = $contador."- ".$resultadoX->meta_key." => ".
    "<input value=".$correspondencias[$contador]." id='correspondencia".$contador."'/>".
    "</p>"; //descobrir como colocar $contador + 1 para imprimir, a fim de que inicialize com 0 o contador e o for do correspondencias
    
    $contador++;

    //$datacount = implode('-',$resultado_array);

    ?>

   <?php

   }

   ?>

   <button id="button2" name="triplify" onclick="atualizaValores()" class="button-primary" >Triplificar</button>

   </div>

  <?php

  }


 }

}

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

**php function**

Note you are declaring all your functions inside initialize.....better to declare functions outside of other functions and call them as you need them.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_post_type_search_callback', array( 'OwnersTriplify', 'my_action_post_type_search_callback' ) );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_post_type_search_callback', array( 'OwnersTriplify', 'my_action_post_type_search_callback' ) );

function post_type_search_callback() {
    $data= $_POST['variable'];

    $output= 'i was returned with ajax';
    //need to echo output and exit here
echo $output;
exit();
}
```

**jQuery**
You need to use the word jQuery or define $ for jQuery to work in wordpress.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { // wait for page to finish loading 
   jQuery("#button1").click(function () {

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        data: {
            action: 'post_type_search_callback',
            variable: 45 // enter in anyname here instead of variable, you will need to catch this value using $_POST['variable'] in your php function.
        },
        success: function (output) {
           console.log(output);
        }
    });

  });
});
```

further reading:

http://web-profile.com.ua/wordpress/dev/ajax-in-wordpress/

Comment: thanks man, understanding now but i've got an error when i click on my button, this one: "TypeError: $.ajax is not a function"